# my programme looking for libtbb.so.2 but I have libtbb.so only how to reolve this

Tags: linux, root

I am building a monte carlo event generator in a virtual machine.
The specifications of my system is ubuntu 23.04

While building the Event generator the roor files are looking for "libtbb.so.2"

I tried Installing libtbb by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
```

but it is not installing "libtbb.so.2"

how tp resolve this li

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install libtbb2